# Restore database from pg_dump syntax errors

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

all I am trying to restore my db from pg_dump that I got from my server. I know there are plenty similar question, I tried what was suggested but still can not resolve my issue.
I created my pg_dump via this command:

```
pg_dump name_of_database > name_of_backup_file
```

Then I create new db:

```
createdb -T template0 restored_database
```

Then I restore using this command:

```
psql -1 -f name_of_backup_file.sql restored_database
```

It runs and then I got different syntax errors, for example:

```
psql:nurate_pg_dump.sql:505: invalid command \nWatch
Query buffer reset (cleared).
psql:nurate_pg_dump.sql:512: invalid command \nThe
psql:nurate_pg_dump.sql:513: invalid command \N
psql:nurate_pg_dump.sql:4098: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "9"
LINE 1: 9 the course is not difficult, but Zauresh Atakhanova is not...
```

I believe since I made pg_dump from the same server, and try to restore it there nothing changed in my server setup, or version of  postgres, so I think my db should restore correctly. How can I resolve these syntax errors?

EDIT: Ok, the problem is not with the syntax:

> CREATE EXTENSION
>      ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql

This error is thrown at this line:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
```

Comment: The `invalid command \N` is typically a result of a _previous_ error in the script. Maybe a `create table` that failed and therefor the transaction should be rolled back. Run psql with the `-a`  option to see the first statement where it failed

Answer (score 3):

try to restore your database with

```
psql restored_database < name_of_backup_file
```